# how to stop Bellman–Ford algorithm depending on the maximum number of arches in the minimum road

Tags: algorithm, graph, bellman-ford

Let G = (V, E) be an oriented and weighted graph that does not contain negative circuits.
How to modify the ford bellman algorithm so that it stops after m + 1 iterations of the while loop.
m is the maximum number of arcs in the minimum path(the minimum road determined based on the weights and not on the number of arches in the road)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a boolean flag to check whether relaxation happened or not, i.e. whether any distance was updated or not.
Since we already know that the shortest path contains m edges, beyond the first m iterations, relaxation doesn't happen and the distances don't change.
So based on the defined boolean flag, you can terminate the loop early.
This improves the time complexity from O(V*E) to O(m*E).

Here's the implementation- https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html#toc-tgt-3